# Getting the error <class 'blog_app.admin.RequestDemoAdmin'>: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[6]' must not be a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been getting this error when trying to migrate my models. However, i am getting this error <class 'blog_app.admin.RequestDemoAdmin'>: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[6]' must not be a ManyToManyField. Any help would be much appreciated.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager



# Create your models here.
class IpModel(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ip

class Blog_Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=1000, editable=False, null=True)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=True, blank=False, null=True)
    blog_content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=False, editable=True, null=True)
    files = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True, auto_now=True, editable=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(IpModel, related_name="post_likes", blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

here is the admin.py file

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog_Post

@admin.register(Blog_Post)
class RequestDemoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = [field.name for field in
  Blog_Post._meta.get_fields()]
```

Comment: The issue is in one of your ModelAdmin classes `RequestDemoAdmin` in `blog_app/admin.py`, can you show this class/file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include a `ManyToManyField` in `list_display`, you include all field names from `Blog_Post._meta.get_fields()` including a `ManyToManyField`.

Filter out ManyToManyFields by using [`Field.many_to_many`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.many_to_many):

```
@admin.register(Blog_Post)
class RequestDemoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in Blog_Post._meta.get_fields() if not field.many_to_many]
```

Alternatively, explicitly define the fields in `list_display`